# Superscript missaligned to subscript

Tags: amsmath, subscripts, superscripts

So this is my (simple) problem, I would like to have the superscript (number 2) in a better position compared to the first case which looks really awful to me. A first solution was to add the parentheses but it seems too bad in a long equation to have much of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\dot{\theta}_{M}^{2} && (\dot{\theta}_{M})^{2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does `\dot\theta_M{}^2` look better to you?

Comment: I would like to have the number 2 exaclty above the letter M

Comment: Then you can just shift the superscript a bit: `\dot\theta_M^{\,\,2}`

Comment: This is very good, you should post it as a possible answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the second layout?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makebox}

\begin{document}

\[ \dot{\theta}_{M}^{2}\qquad \dot{\theta}\!_{M}^{\makebox*{$\scriptstyle M$}{$\scriptstyle 2 $}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]